# Shadow Dom ::content css selector priority?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, shadow-dom

I have shadow dom element like this:

```
<style>
   ::content div{
      padding-left:130px;
   }
</style>

<div class="shadow">
   foo
   <content select="div"></content>
</div>
```

From style loaded on the page try to override this using selector like this

```
.shadow /deep/ div{
   padding-left:50px;
}
```

But selector inside shadow dom is with higher priority. Only way I found to give second selector higher priority is to use important. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the `/deep/` there if your `div` is coming from the light DOM.

I think you've got two selectors of equal importance: `::content div` and `.shadow div`. One way to solve this would be to give your `div` a class, and let the overriding styles use that to boost their score.

ex: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/toqote/3/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Polymer</title>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <style>
      .widget .special {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <polymer-element name="x-foo">
      <template>
        <style>
          ::content > div {
            color: red;
          }
        </style>
        <h1>Hello from x-foo</h1>
        <content select="div"></content>
      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({

        });
      </script>
    </polymer-element>

    <x-foo class="widget">
      <div class="special">Hello World</div>
    </x-foo>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, if we assume that `::content` behaves like any other pseudo-element in terms of specificity, then `::content div` is *less* specific (0, 2) than `.shadow div` (1, 1), as pseudo-elements have the same specificity as type selectors.